# Test equality between coefficients in STATA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, stata, regression-coefficients

I have a very basic question. I use two equations:

\begin{equation}
y_{it}=\beta*X_{it}+\theta*C_{it}+
\sigma_{i}+\tau_{t}+\epsilon_1 \\
z_{it}=\omega*X_{it}+\sigma*C_{it}+
\lambda_{i}+\gamma_{t}+\epsilon_2
\end{equation}

The only differece between the equation is the dependent variables, which represents regional votes for different parties. I estimate them using the STATA command reg2hdfe with cluster at individual level.

I want to test if $\beta$ and $\omega$ are statistically different. I would normally use suest but it is not possible with reg2hdfe. I also try the "stack" solution, but unfortunatly the two dependent variables varies a little bit in their distributions.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Your notation and description are very ambiguous: (1) do you really mean for the coefficients of the $X_{it}$ and $C_{it}$ to be the same in each model? (2) The models you give are identical: changing the subscript "1" to "2" merely changes the notation, not the model.  (3) There is no "DVI" present in either model.  Please edit your post to remove these ambiguities.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was using the worng notation. I hope is more clear now. If not, please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: Have you considered a block bootstrap where you bootstrap $\beta-\omega$?